# How to merge two different trained datasets together

Tags: python, detectron, dataset

I trained a custom dataset but now I want to merge it with different pre-trained dataset in detectron2!

Comment: What is a pre-trained dataset?

Comment: By pre trained dataset I meant that it was trained already ex: (on other device) and due you have any solution for this?